# What is a closed surface for electric flux?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Can every 3 dimensional surface be considered as a closed surface for the purpose of electric flux? I have read that any surface which divides the space into inside and outside is a closed surface. I think any 3D surface would satisfy that. Is that true?

Comment: What do you mean by a 3D surface?  A balloon is a closed surface, a crumpled up sheet of plastic is not a closed surface.

Answer (score 1):

Forget outside and inside. Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth sub-manifold in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. a surface. We say that $\Sigma$ is *closed* if and only if $\partial \Sigma = 0$ which is to say it has no boundary.

For example, if we took a two-dimensional disc of unit radius, then its boundary would be a circle, and so $\partial \Sigma = S^1 \neq 0$ and so it would *not* be a closed surface.

On the other hand, if I took a sphere $S^2$, then its boundary is zero, and it can completely enclose a portion of charge. Yet again, if I took a *ball* this time, its boundary would be a sphere, and so a ball is not closed. However, if I apply this boundary operator again, I get zero, because the boundary of a sphere is zero, or another way to see it is the boundary of a boundary is zero ($\partial^2 = 0$).

Gauss' law is the statement that $d\star E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ and if we integrate over a closed $\Sigma$, we have,

$$\int_\Sigma d \star E = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}Q$$

where $Q$ is the total charge enclosed by the closed surface, $\Sigma$. In language you may be more familiar with, the flux of the field through the closed surface is proportional to the charge it encloses.